How to authenticate dhis2 users using Identity server in ASP.NET Core
I have developed Identity server in ASP.NET Core; the problem is I want to use dhis2 users credentials to authenticate the user and get the token that can be used in authentication of the APIs.
Here is my implementation - Identity Server config class:
public class Config
{
     public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
     {
         return new List<ApiResource>
         {
             new ApiResource("myresourceapi", "My Resource API")
             {
                 Scopes =
                 {
                     new Scope("openid")
                 }
             }
         };
     }

     public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
     {
         return new[]
         {
             new Client
             {
                 ClientId = "application-key-2024",
                 AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                 ClientSecrets = 
                     { 
                         new Secret("001b8a318-71dc-6700-982e-dd592d0f131".Sha256()) 
                     },
                 RedirectUris = { "http://www.example.org" },
                 AllowedScopes = { "openid"},
                 RequireConsent = false
             }
         };
     }
}

Program.cs class
using IdentityServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
             .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
             .AddOperationalStore(options =>
             {
                 options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                 options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30; // interval in seconds
             })
             .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
             .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseIdentityServer();

app.Run();

My service Program.cs class that consumes the token generated
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = "https://localhost:7197";
            o.Audience = "myresourceapi";
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("PublicSecure", policy => policy.RequireClaim("application-key-2024", "001b8a318-71dc-6700-982e-dd592d0f131"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Controller class in micro service class:
namespace Data_Uploading_Service.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UploadController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "PublicSecure")]
        public String DataApi()
        {
            return "You have been authenticated";
        }
    }
}

So now in order to be authenticated from post man you should provide client ID, client secret, scope and grant_type but what I want is to provide username and password e.g uname = admin, password = district
